# About "Always inverting except when you can't" of OPA

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverting-amplifier, non-inverting

Recently, I read [here](http://readingjimwilliams.blogspot.com/2011/09/book-1-chapter-7.html):

> Always inverting except when you can't

Always adopt *inverting*, the reason for which is that noise can be reduced.

Why? Could anyone explain in detail?

I also have a problem.

With a single-rail power supply e.g. a +5 V - 0 V system, I can't adopt an inverting amplifier except when I add a DC-DC converter to +-5 V system power.

Single-rail power supplies are very common in modern analog circuits, so is *always inverting* not suitable for modern analog circuits?

Comment: I don't know why an inverting amplifier would have less noise, but it is usually possible to shift the input signal to around half the supply voltage to make an inverting amplifier on a single 5V (or other) supply.

Comment: An inverting amplifier usually has an input resistance that is much less than a non-inverting amplifier. The high input resistance of the non-inverting amplifier makes a better antenna for noise pickup., and the high resistance also makes more noise.

Comment: So adding a resistor to GND to match the impedance of the feedback network should take care of that.

Comment: OK! As @Audioguru mentioned, if I have necessary on the terminated input resistor, inverting amplifier is good choice. But if my system operate only single-rail(5V - 0V), can't the inverting amplifier be used?

Comment: @curlywei It can be used but with offset (usually with Vsupply/2). And obtained configuration often called differential amplifier. Two pole supply is easier because your input signal is probably referenced to ground and your center point of opamp is 0V, but you can add "local reference" with differential amplifier configuration with Vsupply/2 and use it as "local ground point" in single supply configuration.

Comment: @Audioguru could you explain what do you mean by "the high resistance also makes more noise"? I agree with your 2 previous sentences, but I don't understand how the high input resistance of a non-inverting configuration will produce noise. I have never seen an analysis that considers that as a source of noise.

Comment: Whether or not a high impedance input makes more noise depends on the source impedance, since the two impedances are in parallel to GND (or return). So you can measure high noise with an open-circuit input that disappears when the amp is connected to a low impedance source.

Comment: Can yoy explain why you think you can't use inverting amp? If you have 0V and 5V supply, you are only limited by the input voltage range and the output voltage range of the op-amp. For any suitably biased signal it does not matter if the gain is inverting or non-inverting.

Comment: A high resistance produces more thermal noise in it than a low ,resistance. The resistance of the source is usually lower then it determines the amount of noise.

Comment: @Audioguru ok, by the way you wrote it seemed like you were referring to the input resistance of the op-amp and not the source impedance. The input impedance of a non-inverting op-amp doesn't matter unless the source impedance is high too

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Always adopt inverting, the reason for which is that noise can be reduced.

I'm not sure where you got that from. Jim Williams didn't say that in his article, neither did Kent Lundberg in the blog you're citing above.

Jim Williams stated that the most important reason why he uses the inverting configuration is because the reduced distortion he got from common-mode induced effects. Since the virtual ground is fixed and not moving (as in the non-inverting case), then it should not "excite" the amplifier's input stage that much, which means that there's less distortion produced.

When it comes to intrinsic noise of the amplifier, **the non-inverting amplifier has a better input-referred noise due to the larger signal gain**. Even if you make the inverting amplifier have the same signal gain as a non-inverting one, the input-referred noise will keep being worse for the inverting amplifier due to the "1 + .." term of the noise gain.

High impedance nodes are, indeed, prone to capacitive coupling, that's true. But the node at the (+) terminal of a non-inverting amplifier also has, at least, the  source impedance connected to it, and if it's in order of a few kohm or less, then that node isn't that high impedance anymore. Of course, if you have 1Mohm or higher connected there, it's another story.

If the inverting amplifier you're intending to use is AC coupled, then you can easily use a voltage divider to get around VCC/2 at the (+) op-amp input and get this same bias voltage at the output.

Answer (score 6):

Non-inverting configurations can have less noise in follower applications, because they don't need resistors for this, while inverting followers do. For audio, most of the time, you don't need the absolutely lowest noise though, low distortion is far more important.

The main advantage of the inverting amp for AC applications is that you get less distortion, because the input voltage is constant. CMRR and input impedance of the op-amp don't matter and relax amplifier selection.

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible that he’s referring to amplifiers that aren’t operational amplifiers, op amps being characterised by a long-tailed pair which intuitively would have similar noise characteristics in either inverting or non-inverting modes.  The most trivial transistor amplifier circuits - common emitter or common source - are inherently inverting and so adding an extra transistor to invert the signal again would result in more noise.